# Magento Bug :: Import stuck

Tags: magento-1.9, error, export

I have try to import values of attributes, in my excel contains 60 of records, but only 43 records imported, what about my remaining values.

[image: screen shots]

Comment: Once go through these https://understandinge.com/magmi-mistakes/.

Comment: this is not magmi

Comment: ok. I see. Then chk https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-export-issues.htm

Comment: am already read this, but no use,

Comment: my import working,  its stuck particular count of records, is there any memory error

Comment: You can always increase [memory_limit = 128M ] as per need for large data.[make it 1024]http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/allowed-memory-size-exausted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43289/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arjun).

Comment: this is my memory limit

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oFwjSkJ.png

Comment: still i get error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43293/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arjun).

Comment: Could you also share the excel file?

Comment: @AkifGumussu : am post all details into chat box,

Comment: @AkifGumussu : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42290/jeeva

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6haqixvf617dcuw/not%20author.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Are there any errors being reported in system.log or exception.log ? it looks like you might also have some permission issues as there are images missing in your screenshot.

Comment: @DanCarlyon : could you pls explain briefly

Comment: Down the left hand side of your screenshot you have a bunch of broken images, they are either missing (404) or not accessible (403 permission denied) could lead to an issue with the importer as a whole. Should be information in your logs as to what has gone wrong.